# Swift - Coding A Tie Function in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm 13 and trying to follow a Swift tutorial by Brian Advent. He's teaching me how to do a simple tic tac toe game. I'm trying to code a tie function in Swift after many hours of research I found a lot of code but nothing that will help me.

This is my message to the winner:

```
if winner != "" { //if winner is something

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Tic Tac Toe", message: "The winner is \(winner)!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        //TODO reset the fields
        self.resetField()
     }))
     self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

And this is the message in the case of a tie:

```
else if winner == "" {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Tic Tac Toe", message: "It was a tie", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        //TODO reset the fields
        self.resetField()
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But when I enter this code in and run it, it brings out the "It's a tie" alert because at the start there is still no winner.

Now what I need is a code that tells me when are the spaces all filled so the "It's a tie" block isn't called.

*I also have this code if it is any help. It checks if there is a winner:*

```
func checkResults(){
    var winner = ""
    if fields[0].player == "Steve" && fields[1].player == "Steve" && fields[2].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[0].player == "Creeper" && fields[1].player == "Creeper" && fields[2].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[3].player == "Steve" && fields[4].player == "Steve" && fields[5].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[3].player == "Creeper" && fields[4].player == "Creeper" && fields[5].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[6].player == "Steve" && fields[7].player == "Steve" && fields[8].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[6].player == "Creeper" && fields[7].player == "Creeper" && fields[8].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[0].player == "Steve" && fields[3].player == "Steve" && fields[6].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[0].player == "Creeper" && fields[3].player == "Creeper" && fields[6].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[1].player == "Steve" && fields[4].player == "Steve" && fields[7].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[1].player == "Creeper" && fields[4].player == "Creeper" && fields[7].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[2].player == "Steve" && fields[5].player == "Steve" && fields[8].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[2].player == "Creeper" && fields[5].player == "Creeper" && fields[8].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[0].player == "Steve" && fields[4].player == "Steve" && fields[8].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[0].player == "Creeper" && fields[4].player == "Creeper" && fields[8].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }else if fields[2].player == "Steve" && fields[4].player == "Steve" && fields[6].player == "Steve"{
        winner = "Steve"
    }else if fields[2].player == "Creeper" && fields[4].player == "Creeper" && fields[6].player == "Creeper"{
        winner = "Creeper"
    }
```

**Edited to include Daniel T's function:**

The final working `allFieldsFull()` code:

```
  else if allFieldsFull() == true && winner == "" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Tic Tac Toe", message: "It's a tie", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            //TODO reset the fields
            self.resetField()
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thank you for the help it is greatly appreciated :)
If you have any questions please comment down below

Comment: Hm... That looks right to me. You took out this line right? "else if fields[0].player == "" && fields[1].player == "" && ..."

Comment: No, it's in the check the winner code in the question @LyndseyScott

Comment: Glad it works :) But you don't actually have the if else statement twice in your code back to back like that, right? You only need it once. And also, select the checkmark next to Daniel T's answer to accept it since it helped a lot with your code.

Comment: It doesnt work @LyndseyScott even though I followed what you said

Comment: Oh, I thought you said it works. One sec...

Comment: Oh, I see. There's one more problem with Daniel T's method. `if fields[i]` should be `if fields[i].player` so just update that method accordingly. I've made the edit to Daniel's answer myself so you can follow that as a guideline.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I'll see if it works

Comment: @LyndseyScott It doesnt seem to work. I just wanna thank you so much for helping me with my code i really appreciate it

Comment: @LyndseyScott Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: I changed the logic a bit. Try that function now.

Comment: @LyndseyScott trying it now

Comment: @LyndseyScott It works! Thank you so much because of your help I'm getting a new basketball! I really appreciate your help

Comment: You did some pretty good work yourself! And congrats on the basketball! ;)

Comment: Brian Advent's checkResults which actually should be (CheckForWinCondition) is terribly written. See below for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Your code never checks to see if the game is over. It only checks to see if someone won.

You need an if statement that checks to see if all squares are full, if they are, and winner == "", *then* the game is a tie.

**-EDIT-**

Have you learned about loops and writing your own functions yet? The way to solve your new problem is to create a function that loops through all of the fields.

```
func allFieldsFull() -> Bool {
    for i in 0 ..< 9 {
        if fields[i].player.isEmpty {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I will leave it to you to figure out how to *use* the above. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have code? I know how to do everything but to check if the squares are full is something I need help on

Comment: You know how to check if one square has a mark in it. You do that in the code you posted...

Comment: if fields == [] { alertview code } ? I don't know what it is

Comment: When I check if all the squares have a mark it says it is to complex to compile

Comment: @BobMarley How about you update your question to show the new code you're using to check if all the squares have marks.  Then we can help you from there.

Comment: updated the question, so you can see my code it is under EDIT @LyndseyScott

Comment: Do I use it in the if statement for winner or in the checkResults() if satement

Comment: (I changed the name of my function.) What have you tried? What do you think it means if anyFieldsEmpty() returns true? What if it returns false?

Comment: i tried `else if allFieldsEmpty() != false and allFieldsEmpty() == true and then the alert code` but those didnt work

Comment: @BobMarley Sounds like you're on the right track... Could you post your current code again?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to checkWin for ConnectFour. 
Instead of if statements, you pass in 1, -1 in the StepX and StepY and adjust your loop accordingly.

```
   func isLinearMatch(#column: Int, row: Int, stepX: Int, stepY: Int)->Bool{
        var startGamePieceType = gamePieceTypeOnBoard(column: column, row: row)

            for var i = 0; i < 4; ++i{
            var newX = row + i * stepY
            var newY = column + i * stepX

            if(gamePieceTypeOnBoard(column: newY, row: newX) == GamePieceType.Undefined){
                    return false
                }

            if (startGamePieceType != gamePieceTypeOnBoard(column: newY, row: newX)){
                return false
                }

        }

        return true

    }
```

https://github.com/ericcgu/EGSwiftConnectFour